# Looping through javaScript objects return "undefined" for values 0 and false

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of javascript objects:

```
"result": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "All",
        "entityState": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Phones",
        "entityState": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Laptops",
        "entityState": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Accessories",
        "entityState": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Laptop Bags",
        "entityState": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Cameras",
        "entityState": 0
    }
]
```

Now I want to add one more property to the objects in the array so I loop through the array adding the property to each object:

```
updateCategories(objArray) {
  const newObjArray = [];

  objArray.forEach(obj => {
    const newObject = {
      id: obj.id,
      name: obj.name,
      isActive: false,
    };
   newObjArray.push(newObject);
  });

  return newObjArray;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the contents of the `newObjArray` is like this:

```
 newObjArray = [
{
    "id": undefined,
    "name": "All",
    isActive: undefined
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Phones",
    isActive: undefined
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Laptops",
    isActive: undefined
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Accessories",
    isActive: undefined
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Laptop Bags",
    isActive: undefined
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Cameras",
    isActive: undefined
}
```

]

My questions are:

- why is the value of "id" of the first object undefined instead of 0?
- why is the value of "isActive" undefined instead of false?
- how can I solve this problem cause it breaking my codes?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You never define a `cat` variable, for one thing, did you mean `obj`?

Comment: Apart from the code making no sense, i also don't believe your output. You explicitly make `isActive: false`, there is no reasonable way it gets `undefined`.

Comment: My glass ball gives me a very blurred vision of you not showing us the real and/or all of the code, and that there is a correlation between values being `0` (falsy) in the input, and `undefined` in the output.

Comment: Consider using `map` or `reduce` instead of `forEach`.

Comment: The `cat` that was in the code earlier was a typo, I have fixed that (Talking to CertainPerformance).

Comment: Please believe me, the output is exactly like what I described though it returns `true` if I make `isActive: true`. I find that behaviour strange. It might help to let you know that I am writing the code in a `vuex` state management store - (talking to ASDFGerte). I have used both `map` and `reduce` and even `forLoop` still the same output - (talking to evolutionxbox)

Comment: @KenMadukaKenny Something is modifying your array after the fact. Put this inside your function just before the return: `console.log(JSON.stringify(newObjArray))`. This should show you that your code is working as expected and that something else is modifying your array after you have returned it.

Comment: You are right, I tried you suggestion and it displays the expected output. But on converting it back to JSON object so I can save it to state the strange behaviour returned. I think the issue is `vue` centric. I'm still confused.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
result = result.map(_val =>{
  _val.isActive = false
  return _val
})
```

here is a stackblitz with it working,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-incjfr

if you right click on the white box to the right, inspect element and look in the console log you will see that it delivers the correct result

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I just found out that the problem is not from the loop. I think it is something peculiar to vuex and vuejs state management. I think I should open a new question for that.